# Looking to write info to a file using print writer from button inputs on a simple GUI application

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, printwriter

## Here is my current code:

Like I said before, I'm looking to write info to a file using print writer from button the inputs to a file that displays what has been selected as to look like individual orders.

I'd also like to add a `JOptionPane` that asks for the employee name and all the orders be listed below that name. Ideally I'd like it to add which buttons were selected and the final total formatted such as the program executes. I'd also like it to write to a .txt file and I'm not worried about the OPEN button working, just the save and total.

```
//Import
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.io.*;`

public class IceCream extends JFrame
{

   //Constants for window width and height
   private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 700;
   private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 250;

   /*
      Button Variables
   */

  //Ice cream flavors
   private JRadioButton bVan; //Vanilla Radio button
   private JRadioButton bStraw; //Strawberry Radio button
   private JRadioButton bChoc; //Chocolate radio button

   //Nuts?
   private JCheckBox cbNuts; //Checkbox for Nuts
   private JCheckBox cbCherr; //Checkbox for Cherries

   //Syrup
   private JRadioButton bChocSyrup; //Radio button for Chocolate syrup
   private JRadioButton bCaramSyrup; //Radio button for Caramel syrup
   private JRadioButton bNoSyrup; //Radio button for No syrup


   /* WIP */
   //Buttons for Open, Save and Close features. 
   private JButton Save;
   private JButton Open;
   private JButton Total;

   //Button Groups for Ice Cream flavors and Syrup flavors
   private ButtonGroup iceCreamGroup;
   private ButtonGroup syrupGroup;

   //Panels for the button groups
   private JPanel iceCreamPanel; //IceCream flavor Panel
   private JPanel nutsPanel; //Nuts or no nuts panel
   private JPanel syrupPanel; //Syrup flavors panel
   private JPanel buttonPanel; //Panel for Save, Open, and Total buttons



   /**
      CONSTRUCTOR   
   */

   public IceCream()   
   {    
      //Window title
      setTitle("Icecream Orders");

      //Set size
      setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);

      //Default close operation
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   

      //Calling buildPanel method
      buildPanels();

      //Grid Layout
      setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

      //Adding the panel to JFrame
      add(iceCreamPanel);
      add(nutsPanel);
      add(syrupPanel);
      add(buttonPanel);


      //Visibility
      setVisible(true);  

   } //End IceCream

   /**
      Building the Panels,
      Initializing variables
   */

   private void buildPanels()
   {
      //Initializing the flavor radio butons and adding them to the Buton Group
      bVan = new JRadioButton("Vanilla", true);
      bStraw = new JRadioButton("Strawberry"); 
      bChoc = new JRadioButton("Chocolate");

      iceCreamGroup = new ButtonGroup();
      iceCreamGroup.add(bVan);
      iceCreamGroup.add(bStraw);
      iceCreamGroup.add(bChoc);

      //Initializing the Checkbox for nuts and cherries
      cbNuts = new JCheckBox("Nuts?");
      cbCherr = new JCheckBox("Cherries?");

      //Initializing the Syrup radio butons and adding them to the Button Group
      bChocSyrup = new JRadioButton("Chocolate", true);
      bCaramSyrup = new JRadioButton("Caramel");
      bNoSyrup = new JRadioButton("None");

      syrupGroup = new ButtonGroup();
      syrupGroup.add(bChocSyrup);
      syrupGroup.add(bCaramSyrup);
      syrupGroup.add(bNoSyrup);

      //Initializing the Buttons
      Save = new JButton("Save Order");
      Open = new JButton("Open Order");
      Total = new JButton("Total");
      //Associating action listener to the total button
      Total.addActionListener(new TotalButtonListener());

      //Initializing the panels
      iceCreamPanel = new JPanel();
      nutsPanel = new JPanel();
      syrupPanel = new JPanel();
      buttonPanel = new JPanel();

      //Seting borders of the panels
      iceCreamPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Ice Cream Flavor"));
      nutsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Nuts?"));
      syrupPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Syrup Flavor"));

      //Adding the objecs to the respective panels
      iceCreamPanel.add(bVan);
      iceCreamPanel.add(bStraw);
      iceCreamPanel.add(bChoc);

      nutsPanel.add(cbNuts);
      nutsPanel.add(cbCherr);

      syrupPanel.add(bChocSyrup);
      syrupPanel.add(bCaramSyrup);
      syrupPanel.add(bNoSyrup);

      buttonPanel.add(Save);
      buttonPanel.add(Open);
      buttonPanel.add(Total);  
   }//End buildPanels

   /**
      Action listener class to calculate he total cost
      of the ice cream.
   */
   private class TotalButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         double total = 1.5;
         //Creating a new deciaml format using DecimalFormater
         DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##.##");

         //Calculating total price using .isSelcted method
         if(cbNuts.isSelected())
           total += 0.50;

         if(cbCherr.isSelected())
           total += 0.50;

         if(bChocSyrup.isSelected())
            total += 0.75;

         if(bCaramSyrup.isSelected())
            total += 0.75;    

         //Calculating sales tax
         double tax = total * 0.06;

         //DecimalFormat for total and tax
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total: $" + (formatter.format(total + tax)) +
                                    " ($" + formatter.format(total) + " + $"
                                     + formatter.format(tax) + " tax)");

  } //End actionPermormed
   } //End TotalButtonListener       

   //Embedded Main method
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      new IceCream();

   } //End Main

} //End Class
```

Comment: [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: And I want a million dollars. Now what is your specific question?

Comment: i want to link the save button to a .txt that writes which buttons were selected with the total included. new to GUI and not sure how to do that, cant find anything specific in my textbook

Comment: Use the link posted by @MadProgrammer to create a write file function. Then create a button listener to call that functions. Draft up something and then we can help you with it .

Comment: im working on it right now, ill comment it in a minute